# Using a C# WebForms asp:BulletedList with 3 urls in the list

Tags: c#, webforms

I need to keep using a list box to do this as there are a number of other dependencies on the control being a list box.

Ultimately I want each list item to consist of 3 distinct URL's so:

- [Url1](http://www.google.com) [Url2](http://www.yahoo.com) [Url3](http://www.bing.com)

which would be HTML of:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Url1</a><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Url2</a><a href="http://www.bing.com">Url3</a></li>
</ul>
```

So in my ASPX page I am maintaing there is already:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="lstDashboards" runat="server" DisplayMode="Text"</asp:BulletedList>
```

And in code behind I have the following to populate the list:

```
private void GuiSideMenuBuild(Int64 aUserId)
{
    //Always clear any dashboards
    lstDashboards.Items.Clear();

    //Get the dashboards from the database
    DashboardsForUserGetDto userDashboards = DashboardBL.Instance.DashboardsForUserGet(Convert.ToInt32(aUserId));

    const string HREF_DASHBOARD_EDIT = "<a href=\"#\" id=\"edit-dashboard-link\" class=\"dialog-link\">Edit...</a>";
    const string HREF_DASHBOARD_DELETE = "<a href=\"#\" id=\"delete-dashboard-link\" class=\"dialog-link\">Delete...</a>";

    foreach (TableDashboardDashboardDtoBase userDashboard in userDashboards.Dashboards)
    {
        string listItemText = userDashboard.Title;
        if (userDashboard.DashboardId == DashboardId)
            listItemText += HREF_DASHBOARD_EDIT + HREF_DASHBOARD_DELETE;

        ListItem listItem = new ListItem
            {
                Text = listItemText,
                Value = Convert.ToString(userDashboard.DashboardId),
                Selected = userDashboard.DashboardId == DashboardId
            };
        lstDashboards.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
}
```

However the HTML that the control is producing has escaped all the supplied HTML so that I end up with something like:

```
&lt;&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; id=&quot;...
```

which means that the resulting HTML is "broken" and the URL's don't work. So my question is:

How can I keep using the existing list box (ie. asp:BulletedList) but supply it Text for the item so that it will produce valid HTML so that I can have 3 separate URL's?

I have already tried HTML Encoding the string before adding it to listItem.Text but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for a UserControl here - you don't use any server-side components, you're just generating markup. Why not just do this in your .aspx page?

```
<ul>
<% foreach (TableDashboardDashboardDtoBase userDashboard in userDashboards.Dashboards)
{
%>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Url1</a><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Url2</a><a href="http://www.bing.com">Url3</a></li>
<%
}
%>
</ul>
```

Either that, or use a repeater:

**HTML**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate><li><a href="http://www.google.com">Url1</a><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Url2</a><a href="http://www.bing.com">Url3</a></li></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Repeater1.DataSource = userDashboards.Dashboards
Repeater1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks RGraham but unfortunately as I stated at the top of the post "I need to keep using a list box to do this as there are a number of other dependencies on the control being a list box." I need to keep this a list box.

Comment: @TheEdge Sorry, missed that. But the `ListItem` class does not allow for HTML as the Text, nor does it allow for child controls. Add a `runat=server` to my first example and you should be able to use it server-side with minimal code refactoring